# SQL = Primary Key compuesta por 3 claves foraneas compuestas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo realizar la siguiente consulta, pues busque por varios lados pero no logure encontrar una respuesta:

Tengo 4 tablas:

1. Tabla Usuario: su PK es *Documento* int
2. Tabla Producto: su PK es compuesta por la PK de Usuario + *idProducto* int
3. Tabla Servicio: su PK es compuesta por la PK de Usuario + *idServicio* int
4. Tabla ProductosUsadosEnServicio: (Aqui tengo el problema) esta tabla se compone únicamente por las PK de las primeras tablas

```SQL
Create Table ProductosUsadosEnServicios(
    idProducto int not null,
    idServicio int not null,
    Documento int not null  
    primary key (idProducto, idServicio, Documento)
    foreign key (idProducto, Documento) references Producto(idProducto, Documento)
    foreign key (idServicio, Documento) references Servicio(idServicio, Documento)
    foreign key (Documento) references Usuario(Documento)
)
Go
```

El Error que me da SQL es el siguiente:

```
Mens. 8140, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2
Se ha especificado más de una clave en la restricción de columna FOREIGN KEY, tabla 'ProductosUsadosEnServicios'.
Mens. 8148, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2
Se ha especificado más de una restricción de columna FOREIGN KEY para la columna 'Documento', tabla 'ProductosUsadosEnServicios'.
Mens. 8140, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2
Se ha especificado más de una clave en la restricción de columna FOREIGN KEY, tabla 'ProductosUsadosEnServicios'.
Mens. 8148, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2
Se ha especificado más de una restricción de columna FOREIGN KEY para la columna 'Documento', tabla 'ProductosUsadosEnServicios'.
```

Llevo rato dándole vueltas y no logro verle una solución; quizás alguien pueda verla.
Desde ya MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes un poco mal la sintaxis. Al momento de especificar la llave foranea, no tienes que especificar las columnas de la tabla referenciada porque serán las columnas de su llave primaria.

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario
(
    Documento INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(Documento)
);

CREATE TABLE Producto
(
    Documento  INT NOT NULL, 
    idProducto INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(idProducto, Documento)
);

CREATE TABLE Servicio
(
    Documento  INT NOT NULL, 
    idServicio INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(idServicio, Documento)
);

CREATE TABLE ProductosUsadosEnServicios
(
    idProducto INT NOT NULL, 
    idServicio INT NOT NULL, 
    Documento  INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idProducto, idServicio, Documento), 
    FOREIGN KEY (idProducto, Documento) REFERENCES Producto, 
    FOREIGN KEY (idServicio, Documento) REFERENCES Servicio, 
    FOREIGN KEY (Documento) REFERENCES Usuario
);
```